# a better expression or single word for "developer usabilty"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms, software

I am looking for a better english expression or single word that describes this:

**developer usabilty**:
*the quality of language, tooling, IDE and APIs for frictionless development.*

example usages:

> The *developer usabilty* of our clould offering is very bad because our users need to know way to many details.
>
> The *developer usabilty* of the APIs in that library could be improved because noone can remember these long names.
>
> We are like Apple Inc. but for developers. We care deeply about the *developer usabilty* of our SDK.

A collocial term is OK, but it should be widely understood.

Comment: "Usability" is the correct word, for developer tools or a tool's other intended audiences. A quick google search for "developer usability" will show many white papers that simply use "usability". For instance, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997575.aspx.

Comment: "Usabilty" seems too tightly associated with graphical user interfaces.

Comment: It's not. It's the generally accepted term. It's frequently used to refer to APIs. A simple Google search will show that.

Comment: When I search for *developer usability* I get a lot of results related to "developers doing someting about the usabilty of their products". Like developers doing usability testing or developers that also do UI/UX design and such.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=api+usability. https://www.google.com/search?q=cloud+usability.

Comment: The links are often very old or often seem to focus more on the end user, not the developer itself. I still think there is a level of ambiguation that I am  not comfortable with.

Comment: I'd say 'developer productivity'

Comment: The October 2016 Journal article "Improving API Usability" is old? You're looking for an excuse to complicate this. Introducing a new term when it's not needed isn't great usability.

Comment: By the way, you would not need the definite article with "developer usability" in initial position there.

Answer (score 3):

You may be looking for ***user–friendliness***. The *developers* in question are *users* in this context.
Perhaps you can even adapt it as ***developer-friendliness*** to make it more explicit.

M-W:

> **[user–friendly](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/user%E2%80%93friendly)**
> *adjective*
>
> :  easy to learn, use, understand, or deal with : ***user–friendly**
> software*
>
> - **user–friendliness** *noun*

Wordnik:

> **[developer-friendly](https://www.wordnik.com/words/developer-friendly)**
>
> **Examples**:
>
> But Apple changed the game in 2008 with its
> developer-friendly App Store, which now hosts some 350,000 apps that
> have been downloaded over 10 billion times on the iPhone, iPod touch
> and iPad.
>
> The San Francisco-based startup hosts all the computing functions of
> its web developer-friendly telephony service on Amazon Web Services, a
> business model that enables Twilio to differentiate itself even
> further from its voice API cohorts.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have just found a good candidate:

**developer experience (DX)**

https://www.google.com/search?q=developer%20experience&rct=j

Looks pretty canonical to me. It also is a good counterpart to **user experience (UX)**.